# Выполнение какого-либо действия по нажатию мыши на объект - Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Суть такова: персонаж передвигается по NavMesh, управление происходит по нажатию правой кнопки мыши, мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на определённый GameObject он сначала доходил до него, а потом при достижении позиции объекта, по которому мы кликнули, проигрывал определённую анимацию.

Answer (score 0):

На такие вопросы отвечали 65534 раз. Пусть этот будет 65535-ый, последний.

---

Если у вас UI объект прикрепите на него компонент [`Button`](https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html). Пишите в скрипте:

```cs
using UnityEngine.UI;
...
public Button JustAButton;
...
private void Start()
{
    JustAButton.onClick.AddListener
    (
        delegate()
        {
            //Тут ваши действия
        }
    );
}
```

Если у вас 3D объект используйте [`Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html):

```cs
if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), 10)
{
    //Тут ваши действия
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Upd:
для правой кнопки тебе придется использовать `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)` и пускть луч из камеры в направлении курсора. Там уже будешь смотреть по какому коллайдеру ты попал. Тебе уже написали .

Ты можешь использовать [OnMouseDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html) метод на объекте, по которому ты кликаешь.

Что-то типа такого:

```
    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        _agent.SetDestination(transform.position);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(_agent.pathStatus == NavMeshPathStatus.completed || Math.Approximately(agent.remainingDistance, 0)
        {
          // твоя анимация
        }
    }
```

Выше это если ты используешь NavMeshAgent. Если делаешь без него, то тогда путь будешь искать до своего объекта:

```
NavMesh.SamplePosition(transform.position, out var navMeshHit, searchRadius, _areaMask); // найдешь ближайшую точку на навмеше к объекту, по которому ты кликнул, на котором же будет висеть этот скрипт
далее найдешь массив векторов-вейпоинтов до найденной точки от точки старта
NavMesh.CalculatePath(startPoint, navMeshHit.position, _areaMask, _path); //_path это _path = new NavMeshPath(), который ты создашь заранее 
var waypoints = _path.GetCorners(); // получишь массив векторов.
```

Далее по мере продвижения твоего объекта к цели, будешь смотреть достиг ли ты конечного вейпоинта, которым будет waypoints[waypoints.Length - 1]. Проверить достижение вейпоинта можно сравнивая квадрат расстояния от твоего объекта до текущего вейпоинта, к которому ты едешь . типа `if(Vector3.SqrMagnitude(waypoints[currentWaypoint] - agent.position) < yourSqrDistThreshold)`.. Ну а как доедешь уже запустишь свою анимацию. Мне было лень писать весь код по-нормальному, но думаю дошло. [Вот сюда еще зайди](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMesh.CalculatePath.html).